# Размещение переменной в регистре

Tags: c++, память

> > Register variables
>
> The maximum number of integer register variables is approximately six
>   in 32-bit systems and fourteen in 64-bit systems.The maximum number of
>   floating point register variables is eight in 32-bit systems
>   andsixteen in 64-bit systems. Some compilers have difficulties making
>   floating point register variables in 32-bit systems unless the SSE2
>   (or later) instruction set is enabled.The compiler will choose the
>   variables that are used most for register variables. This includes
>   pointers and references, which can be stored in integer registers.
>   Typical candidates for register variables are temporary intermediates,
>   loop counters, function parameters, pointers, references, 'this'
>   pointer, common subexpressions, and induction variables (see below).**A
>   variable cannot be stored in a register if its address is taken, i.e.
>   if there is a pointer or reference to it.** Therefore, you should avoid
>   making any pointer or reference to a variable that could benefit from
>   register storage.

[Источник](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf)

Не очень понимаю, почему переменная не может быть размещена в регистрах?

Comment: Потому что адрес, содержащийся в указателе - это адрес в оперативной памяти. Невозможно указать на то, чего нет в памяти

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переменная не может быть размещена в регистрах, если вам понадобится её адрес:

```
register int d;
scanf("%d", &d);
```

В данном случае функции `scanf` требуется адрес переменной `d`, чтобы записать туда введённое пользователем число.

Если переменная размещена в регистре, естественно, у неё нет адреса в оперативной памяти.

P.S. Всё это очень-очень сильно устарело. Современные компиляторы прекрасно размещают локальные переменные в регистрах без дополнительных указаний.

Comment: *"Всё это очень-очень сильно устарело. Современные компиляторы прекрасно размещают локальные переменные в регистрах"* Да и к тому же, `register` выбросили из C++17.